# How to swap wETH for ETH on Polygon network?

Tags: ether, metamask, uniswap, polygon, wrapped-tokens

The current largest mining pool Ethermine has [an option to be paid in wETH through the Polygon network instead of in ETH on the mainnet.](https://ethpool.freshdesk.com/support/solutions/articles/8000060967-ethermine-org-payout-policy)

Through MetaMask on the Polygon network, I see my wETH in my wallet, but MetaMask does not offer an option to swap to ETH, only other wrapped tokens. Is it possible to use MetaMask to swap wETH to ETH?  If I use an exchange like Uniswap, can I pay for the gas fees in wETH or do I already need ETH to pay for fees? Will my swapped ETH exist on Polygon or on mainnet?

Comment: You don't need WETH on Polygon because ETH is already an ERC-20 contract. Perhaps you meant how to obtain WMATIC?

Comment: No, I was paid by the pool in wETH on Polygon. So from my understanding if the exchange does not support Polygon then I need to use a bridge to mainnet. And I also have the separately swap wETH for ETH.

Comment: Also https://weth.io/ says ETH is not ERC-20 compliant. Do you mean it is on Polygon?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First of all, the "eth" asset exists in different forms across Ethereum and Polygon. For each blockchain, we have one utility token and other erc20 compliant tokens (+ other standards).

1. Ethereum `eth` - the utility token
2. Ethereum `weth` - the erc20 wrapper for `eth`
3. Polygon `matic` - the utility token
4. Polygon `wmatic` - the erc20 wrapper for `matic`
5. Polygon `weth` - an polygon erc20 representation for polygon `eth` that was bridged from ethereum mainnet

Second of all, any transaction requires gas paid in the native utility token of the chain. So for ethereum you will pay native `eth`, while for polygon you will pay native `matic`.

---

Regarding your bridging question, if you ask to be paid in `weth` on Polygon, you will receive (#5) the polygon erc20 weth token in your wallet. To bridge it to Ethereum Mainnet you will use a service such as the [Polygon Bridge](https://wallet.polygon.technology/) or [Hop Exchange](https://app.hop.exchange). These will convert your polygon weth -> to mainnet (pure) eth.

For Hop you will need to sign one transaction on polygon (requiring utility token for gas: matic) for the transfer.

For the Polygon Bridge (from what I remember) you will need to sign two transactions. One on polygon (requires matic) to send the polygon weth and one on ethereum (requries eth on mainnet) to receive the weth. For this you need to consider having some eth for gas on mainnet in the account before starting the transfer.

Comment: So you're saying ether only exists as wrapped form wETH on Polygon network? This appears to be the case on Hop exchange.

Comment: Yes, on Polygon it only exists as Wrapped Ether (WETH, an ERC20) - case #5

Comment: swap to Matic, send to an exchange, sell for ETH. Using the bridge is a waste of money

Comment: @Mehdi feel free to post as answer.

Answer (score 1):

I contacted MetaSwap support. They confirmed that ETH exists as wETH on Polygon and MetaMask browser extension does not support bridging currently. Instead I can use a bridge like Polygon or Hop to bridge the tokens across networks.

To make transactions within Polygon requires MATIC tokens as the gas token. Previously there were MATIC faucets to provide a little MATIC to get started. However, Polygon bridge has [Swap for gas token](https://wallet.polygon.technology/gas-swap) which can directly convert wETH to MATIC to get started with transactions. I converted 1 MATIC which should be enough to do at least several dozen transactions.